# Keep only values, grouped by a column, which share a value in another column

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I hope the title isn't too confusing.

I have a dataframe, and I'm trying to keep only the values, grouped by `'id'`, that all share the same value in `'validity'`. In other words, the three rows with `id=0` must be kept only if the corresponding 3 values in `validity` are the same (either all three are 0, or all three are 1).

Yet again in other words, if the three values that share an `id` don't all share the same `validity`, filter them out.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

a = np.repeat(np.arange(6), 3)
b = np.random.choice([0, 1], p=[.15, .85], size=18)
c = np.repeat(['dog', 'cat', 'platypus'], 6)

df = pd.DataFrame(zip(a, b, c), columns=['id', 'validity', 'kind'])
```

```
    id  validity      kind
0    0         1       dog
1    0         1       dog
2    0         0       dog
3    1         1       dog # only keep those
4    1         1       dog # only keep those
5    1         1       dog # only keep those
6    2         1       cat
7    2         0       cat
8    2         1       cat
9    3         1       cat
10   3         1       cat
11   3         0       cat
12   4         1  platypus
13   4         0  platypus
14   4         1  platypus
15   5         1  platypus
16   5         0  platypus
17   5         1  platypus
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can filter with `nunique` and `transform`:

```
df = df[df.groupby(['id', 'kind'])['validity'].transform('nunique') == 1]
```